# The highest set value of an integer that's constantly changing

Tags: python

I have a program that constantly changes the value of a variable and I'm willing to find out what was the highest value that was generated during such process. I'm posting a simple piece of coding below that should give you a better idea of what I'm trying to achieve. I was going to set the maxGen variable as the number rolled if the number rolled was greater than maxGen but I think that it's not an efficient way to code it.

```
looped = 0
numbergen = 0
while looped > 3: #how many times a number's supposed to be re-generated
    x = randint(1,1001)
    print(x)
    looped = looped + 1
```

Comment: Why do you think your way is not efficient? How often is the value re-generated? If in a simple loop like this, there are indeed better ways, but what is the real situation like?

Comment: 600,000 variables need to be generated and I was trying to make the code take as little space as possible

Comment: Define 'as little space' here. Memory? Characters of code? You didn't really address the question about how the values are generated though.

Comment: As little space = As little characters of code. Also, it doesn't really matter, they're simply random integers from 1 to 1001 (works like a 1000-sided dice that's being rolled over and over again) and I'm simply trying to find out what was the higest number rolled.

Comment: Then just use a generator expression is `max()`: `max(randint(1, 1001) for _ in xrange(3))` to pick the highest out of 3 random rolls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code will never enter the loop because looped is initialized at 0 and then you do `while looped > 3` (which it isn't).  It should be `while looped < 3`.

The way you proposed is fine.

```
looped = 0
numbergen = 0
max_num = None
while looped < 3: #how many times a number's supposed to be re-generated
    x = randint(1,1001)
    max_num = x if max_num is None else max(x, max_num)
    print(x)
    looped = looped + 1
print('max num: {0}'.format(max_num))
```

Comment: It was just an example, not the actual code, but thanks for spotting that error and solving my problem. I tried to research the max function but I couldn't get my head around it, so ty again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the relevance of that code snippet, but the general way to do this is using `max`:

```
max_gen = 0
...
max_gen = max(max_gen, generated_variable)
```